weird issue with laravel application and nginx fpm
Just wondering if someone could give some guidance. I am attempting to make a laravel app use nginx. I know fpm works because i can see phpinfp when run. The moment I am trying to use the public folder for the laravel app I get this:
10.240.0.26 - - [09/Apr/2024:12:49:34 +0100] "GET /login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url=/login??return_url=/login?return_url=/login?return_url= HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0"

It just keeps appending the login URL. Now I am not the creator of the app, I am just trying to port it from apache to nginx.
This is my default out of the box setup on ubuntu 22.04 (only changes I made so far)
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Allow headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
    }

This is my full NGINX config. It has changed a bit since I asked my question as i try things. Everything else is a default install out of the box.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name console.notlistingmyserver.com;
    root /data/www/consoleapp/console/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;


        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;

    }

 
}

Anyone seen this before?

Can you share the whole nginx configuration file for your project?

Here are a few pointers I think might help.

In your Laravel app, check the login controller, can you dd() at the start of the login method,
or you can check if a middleware or code is causing the redirection, as this issue seems like  something might be redirecting requests within your Laravel application.

The portion of nginx configuration you posted is correct and should work fine,
but your question is missing how you are pointing to laravel public folder.
confirm the root directive is pointing to the right folder and  the nginx user has the right permission on the public folder and the laravel folder also.


server {

    root /path/to/laravel/public;



ensure there is no .htaccess with a rewrite/redirection rule

you can  inspect your log to see if there are any pointer about why it is redirecting  (there should be entries that might give clues)

if none of this works,  you can try clearing caches
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan cache:clear



Based on the provided  nginx server conf the


@rewriterule seem like the culprit, please test with a simplified conf as follows .
    listen 80;
    server_name console.notlistingmyserver.com;
    root /data/www/consoleapp/console/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    # Simplified try_files directive for Laravel
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    }

  
}


good to know it is not (possibly not nginx): My root is : root /data/www/consoleapp/console/public; and that is where the public index.php is located

Hi on further review of the full log, The rewrite rule in your @rewrite location block is rewriting all requests to /index.php, appending ?_url=/ and the original URI. This is unusual for a standard Laravel setup. Typically, the try_files directive is sufficient to handle the rewriting needs for Laravel , i will advice you remove  the @rewrite  Location Block

I already have, i keep trying different configs until the page displays. But reverted  now to the original one i pasted.

do you see anything in your log?
